# Deployed heroku app not loading css

Tags: css, reactjs, express, heroku

I'm using React with an Express backend to build a web-app.

It looks fine locally, as well as on the deployed Heroku site or a custom domain, but only on my computer.

As soon as I try to access it on my phone or on another computer, the CSS doesn't seem to load at all (I just see a mess of images and text).

What could be going wrong? I'm not sure what details I need to give so please let me know and I will happily supply them

Comment: Are there any errors in console? Wrong path in most cases is the reason

Comment: I get this error: `Error during service worker registration: DOMException: Only secure origins are allowed`

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I have a similar problem but it only works in dev and nowhere once I have deployed to Heroku

Comment: Did you find the reason for it?